# How to solve "An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file..." SQL error?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I've got a local .mdf SQL database file that I am using for an integration testing project. Everything works fine on the initial machine I created the project, database, etc. on, but when I try to run the project on another machine I get the following:

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)*

I figure while I am investigating this problem I would also ask the community here to see if someone has already overcome this.

The exception occurs when I instantiate the new data context. I am using LINQ-to-SQL.

```
m_TransLogDataContext = new TransLogDataContext ();
```

Let me know if any additional info is needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question as I have the solution.

I was relying on the automatic connection string which had an incorrect "AttachDbFilename" property set to a location that was fine on the original machine but which did not exist on the new machine.

I'm going to have to dynamically build the connection string since I want this to run straight out of source control with no manual tweaking necessary.

Easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

That because your application have more than one setting to database, try to "Find All" on your solution by search your connection name
likes

I'm using "**EnergyRetailSystemConnectionString**" or you can search by your database name